# What are the hex color code equivalents for the different classifications of stars?

Tags: visible-light, temperature, thermal-radiation, wavelength, stars

Stars appear to be of various colors based on the visible light they emit. I am wondering if there is a hex color code that can be considered to be typified or average for the various classifications and temperature of stars (O, B, A, F, G, K, and M; 0-9)?

I am hoping for a fairly simplistic answer in the form of a list, as I am an artist, not a mathematician.

Comment: This post from astronomy stack exchange might help - [What is the RGB curve for blackbodies?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39994)

Comment: Why do you want a new classification scheme that basically no one will ever use because the current scheme is already embedded into the culture?

Comment: Excellent question. It is simply because I want to color stars roughly correctly in an image I am drawing, and was hoping that there was a list somewhere, or some kind person who could make one.

Comment: @mmesser314 What I understood from that was 'waves of color, a big curve of color, and a ton of math as far over my head as the stars I'm trying to color'. I'm an artist, blast it, not a mathematician. I do appreciate the link, however. =D

Comment: The Morgan-Keenan classification doesn't identify a color, it identifies emission lines of Hydrogen (the [Balmer series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series)). There isn't "a" color associated with the classifications. See [here for details on the MK system](https://pages.uoregon.edu/imamura/122/lecture-4/mk.html)

Comment: Light emitted from a blackbody is a mix of wavelengths. This mix stimulates the three different types of color receptor in the eye. The relative strengths of stimulation determine the color you see. Thus for each temperature hot enough to glow in the visible, there is a color.

Comment: If you want to display those colors on a computer monitor, translating them to RGB makes a lot of sense.

Comment: @KyleKanos, I was vaguely aware of the emission lines of Hydrogen bit of knowledge, thank you for the links. mmesser314, as an artist I am somewhat familiar with the interaction between light, the eye, and the brain, and that almost all light we see is actually a mix, not to mention that the color of objects we perceive is not its' actual color, but rather the frequencies that were reflected and not absorbed.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to perform a series of conversions to get what you want. Here I show you how to use pictures to get a very rough answer. But it should work for what you want.

First for each type of star, you need to know its surface temperature. You can get that from this Hertzsprung-Russell diagram I copied from https://www.mtsu.edu/physics/Astronomy/prelab9_HR_diagram.php.

For example, you can see that a G type star like the Sun has a temperature of about 6000 C.

[image]

Then for each surface temperature, you need to find what color is emitted. Here is the C.I.E. 1931 Chromaticity Diagram. This is a standard chart, but this copy has some extra notes on it. I downloaded it from https://www.ledtronics.com/html/1931ChromaticityDiagram.htm.  For any color, you can see what the X and Y color coordinates of that color are.

The black line in the middle is the colors of blackbodies at various temperatures. 6500 C corresponds to white light. This is about the temperature of the Sun. You can see that the X,Y coordinates of this point are about 0.33,0.33.

For other temperatures, see the yellow numbers along the bottom. Find the temperature you want and go straight up to the black line. That shows you the color and allows you to find the X and Y color coordinates.

[image]

Next you need to convert from X,Y to RGB. Here is a website that helps. [RGB/xy Color Conversion](https://viereck.ch/hue-xy-rgb/). It shows the same Chromaticity diagram. There is a + on it that you can drag around with your mouse. As you drag it, the X,Y and RGB values are calculated.

If you know X,Y, drag the + until you hit it (or get close enough). The RGB you need is displayed. For 0.33,0.33, I get RGB is 255,235,226. Here is a screenshot.

[image]

In summary,

G type star
->  6000 C

->  X,Y = 0.33,0.33

->  RGB = 255,235,226

Comment: Once you have the temperature, there's no need to futz around with chromaticity diagrams and colorspace conversion. Just use the eyedropper tool on an image like [this one](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Color_temperature_black_body_800-12200K.svg) which someone precomputed for you.

Comment: @benrg - Nice. You don't have to know the RGB values. You just copy the pixel you want.

Answer (score 0):

Various lists of hex codes for star classes and temperatures can be found on Mitchel Charity's site vendian.org, along with explanations that to my untrained understanding seem to be a rough match for [mmesser314's explanations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/774725/127348). However, mmesser314's otherwise excellent answer did not provide the hex codes, which was the goal of the question.

The list presented here is taken directly from Mitchel's site, all credit for the work belongs to Mitchel and collaborators. Mitchel's website was also referenced by a [discovermagazine.com article](https://www.discovermagazine.com/the-sciences/a-hex-on-star-colors) and a [todayifoundout.com article](https://www.todayifoundout.com/index.php/2010/03/the-sun-is-white-not-yellow/).

| Sp5(V) | R | G | B | Hexadecimal |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| O | 155 | 176 | 255 | #9bb0ff |
| B | 170 | 191 | 255 | #aabfff |
| A | 202 | 215 | 255 | #cad7ff |
| F | 248 | 247 | 255 | #f8f7ff |
| G | 255 | 244 | 234 | #fff4ea |
| K | 255 | 210 | 161 | #ffd2a1 |
| M | 255 | 204 | 111 | #ffcc6f |

See the linked pages from Mitchet's site for a more detailed [list of known stars and other celestial  object's colors](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/starcolor/) using D65 as the whitepoint or a [list of stellar classes](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/starcolor/UnstableURLs/starcolorsD58.html) using D58 as the whitepoint or [the unauthorized list of the colors of the closest 100 stars](http://www.vendian.org/mncharity/dir3/starcolor/UnstableURLs/colorized_TOP100.html) as of the year 2000.